# Always apply scopes computed for a complex scenario when retrieving objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several scopes that need to be applied for a complex scenario. But currently, I "store" this scenario in a method:

```
def search param1, param2
  results = Model.all
  if param1 == ...
    results = results.scope1
  else
    results = results.scope2
  end
  ...and so on...
end
```

However, I would like to define this complex scenario directly on the model, so that when I do `Model.all` or `Model.where` or whatever, these scopes should be automatically added.

But somehow, I also need to tweak the scenario with some parameters from the outside (see `param1` and `param2` from above).

How can I achieve this? If it is not possible, what's the best of adding complex filtering on a model when searching for results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scope that takes arguments:

```
scope :search, ->(param1, param2) {
  if param1 == ...
    scope1
  else
    scope2
  end
  ...and so on...
}
```

Than you can write `Model.search(param1, param2).scopex....`

Comment: It indeed solves what I am after, but is it readable? I mean, I feel scopes were created for a different job.

Comment: [Scopes are just class methods](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/) that can be reliably chained. I'll say that it is as readable as a class method would be. What is a purpose of the scope in your eyes?